# Deletar dado da tabela sem necessidade de recarregar pagina para atualizar

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tenho uma tabela com dados de um determinado equipamento, acima da tabela tem um campo aonde o nº do equipamento é inserido e quantidade, as demais informações vem do banco através do nº do equipamento. Na ultima coluna de cada tabela existe um botão para excluir está linha, porém para que o efeito ocorra é necessario recarregar a pagina. Porém após o usuario fazer o submit 1x, quando se recarrega a pagina o navegador entende a ação como se tivesse havido outro submit, ou seja, insere novamente o ultimo produto inserido.

Está é a forma como os dados são impressos na tabela

```
while ($result_info = mysql_fetch_array($sql_info))
    {
      $tabela .= '<tr>';
      $tabela .=    '<td>'.$result_info['cod_item'].'</td>';
      $tabela .=    '<td>'.$result_info['desc_item'].'</td>';
      $tabela .=    '<td>'.$result_info['unidade'].'</td>';
      $tabela .=    '<td>'.$result_info['quantidade'].'</td>';
      $tabela .=    '<td>'.$result_info['valor'].'</td>';
      $tabela .=    '<td><a onclick="needToConfirm = false;" style="margin-left: 30px;" title="Excluir" src="../../dist/icons/delete.png"></a></td>'; href="pecas_proposta_incluir_temp_del.php?id={$linhas["id_temp"]}"><img 
      $tabela .=    '</tr>';
    }
echo $tabela;
```

Como podem visualizar os dados são concatenados em um variável, para que quando o usuário insira mais de um item, envés de sobre escrever o item anterior ele cria uma nova linha.

**Resumindo, o que estou precisando é que o usuário possa deletar apenas o item especificado e que seja atualizado na hora sem a necessidade de recarregar a pagina. Se alguém tiver dicas de como fazer o reload da pagina sem causar um submit novamente, ficarei grato.**

Comment: pesquise sobre ajax

Comment: Usa Ajax neste link tem um exemplo de como fazer http://matheuspiscioneri.com.br/blog/ajax-e-php-para-atualizar-sem-refresh/

Comment: Como é feita e exclusão e a inclusão de dados no banco? Você precisa fazer essa diferenciação no PHP, se está fazendo as duas coisas na mesma página. Você precisa enviar para a página um valor que diferencie uma coisa da outra.

Comment: A inclusão e exclusão no momento está na mesma pagina, que é requerido pela pagina aonde os dados são impressos. Estive pensando no que disse, criar uma pagina só para inserir e outra para apagar que após executadas retornem para a principal, dessa maneira não será feito o recarregamento da pagina principal.

Comment: Acho que nem precisa. Mude os parâmetros enviados para a página: quando for excluir, envie o `id` do item numa variável diferente, por exemplo, `&excluir=56`... no PHP vc faz condicionais para verificar o que está sendo enviado e faz a exclusão.

Answer (score 0):

> quando se recarrega a pagina o navegador entende a ação como se tivesse havido outro submit, ou seja, insere novamente o ultimo produto inserido.

Erro clássico. Você deve criar um outro arquivo PHP para fazer a inserção, e após efetuada, o usuário deve ser redirecionado para a página anterior. Ou seja, o arquivo PHP que modifica o banco de dados nunca deve ser o mesmo que mostra os dados na tela para o usuário. Isso é [MVC](https://tableless.com.br/entendendo-o-padrao-mvc-na-pratica/).

> sem a necessidade de recarregar a pagina.

Para isso você pode utilizar o [$.ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp) ou [$.post](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp) do plugin [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)